# jwhois not working

Tags: whois

I have installed jwhois on many systems, but can't get it to work. 
The port 43 is open through the firewall and I can do a telnet to the whois server on port 43, but whenver I run jwhois I get the following error:

```
[Querying whoisserver]
[Unable to connect to remote host]
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Debian Bug [542148](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=542148).

Not fixed in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS unfortunately.

Comment: Ahh thanks. That has been bugging me for some time :)

Comment: This is also noted in the Ubuntu Launchpad for jwhois: [Bug 339913](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jwhois/+bug/339913). The fix is in Natty, Oneiric, and Precise, but _not_ in Lucid or Maverick.

Answer (score 0):

For 10.04:

1. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jwhois/4.0-2
2. Download [jwhois_4.0.orig.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/jwhois_4.0.orig.tar.gz) to `/usr/local/src`.
3. Extract and apply patch:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/src
   tar zxf jwhois_4.0.orig.tar.gz
   cd jwhois*
   wget "https://launchpadlibrarian.net/59543349/jwhois_4.0-2.diff.gz"
   gunzip *.gz
   patch < jwhois_4.0-2.diff
   ```

Then apply the fix for `.com` lookups:

1. Visit http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=542148
2. Edit `src/utils.c`.
3. Change line 291 to:

   ```
   if (error < 0 || !retval)
   ```

Compile and install as usual:

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install`